# How to insert to postgres using Django orm when a generated index field exists

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have a model which has a text field. I have created an index on this field for search purposes:

```
class my_model(models.Model):  

   text = models.TextField(null=True)
   vector = SearchVectorField(null=True, default='')

   #m2m field
   ents = models.ManyToManyField(ent)

class ent(models.Model):
    ph = models.TextField(unique=True)
    ty = models.TextField()
```

Till now, I have inserted to this table using insert and to insert I did not provide any data for the field during insertion. Every thing was fine, but now I have added a `manytomany` field to this model. Since I have not created an explicit thru table I want to change insert code to use Django orm. The problem that I have is when I try to insert to the model using orm with the following statement, I am getting the error:

```
a1 = my_model(text='test')
a1.save()
```

Error:

```
ProgrammingError: column "vector" can only be updated to DEFAULT
DETAIL:  Column "vector" is a generated column.
```

Also, I tried the following with the same error:

```
a1 = my_model(text='test', vector = '')
a1.save()
```

Comment: How did you add the M2M field? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, Please look at the answer again.

Comment: @JPG Please note that I do not think that the problem is related to m2m field, since I am inserting data using direct queries to table. My problem is that I do not know how to specify generated field in creating instances using ORM.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue - but, I didn't get any errors. Can you create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? along with the version of the tools you are using?

Comment: I can't reproduce any of the errors. I was going to say that this is a generated column (by the database) but I also managed to populate it.

Comment: @Memrist Did you use ORM?

Comment: You can find more info here https://pganalyze.com/blog/full-text-search-django-postgres.

Comment: Also please note that the field I created is filled automatically with triggers.

Comment: I did use the ORM. On the trigger issue, I'll check but maybe is a question of versions: in my case `psql 14.7`, `postgres 12.12`, `django 4.2.1`.

Comment: My versions are psql 14.5, postgres 14.5, django 4.2.1.

Comment: You can update your `vector` field in the model with the following line: `vector = SearchVectorField(null=True, blank=True)`. After that, run migration command which is the following: `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate`. I hope your problem will be resolved.

Comment: You can try another solution without changing your DB. Just update the your code into the following: `a1 = my_model()
a1.text = 'test'
a1.save()`